# как проверить, можно ли конвертировать тип данных (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

Например, `a = int(input())` если `input()` может быть конвертировано в целое число?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того чтобы определить что строка число int можно использовать `.isnumeric`:

```py
s = input()
if s.isnumeric():
    a = int(s)
else:
    print('Не число')
```

Если нужно преобразовывать в другие типы, то можно сделать обработку исключений:

```py
try:
    a = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print('Ошибка!')
```

Comment: `'-1'`, `'+1'`, `'  1  '`, `'1_000'` - строки не соответствующие предикату `isnumeric`, но без проблем конвертируемые в `int`. В таких случаях [обработка исключений](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-EAFP) - предпочтительный, и, можно сказать, единственно правильный вариант.